# Weird SCNGeometrySource data

Tags: swift, scenekit

I am trying to access `SCNGeometrySource` content. After inspecting the source I can tell that:

```swift
source.bytesPerComponent = 4
source.componentsPerVector = 3
source.dataStride = 16
source.dataOffset = 0
source.vectorCount = 98304
```

In other terms, I have `98304` vectors of float3.

Yet, when calling

```swift
source.data.withUnsafeBytes { (pointer: UnsafePointer<float3>) in
    for i in 0..<source.vectorCount {
        print((pointer + i).pointee)
    }
}
```

The first printed elements seem about fine, but close to the end, I get weird values close to zero when they shouldn't be, crash from time to time, and memory sanitiser does detect a heap overflow.

I don't understand how can a heap overflow being caused even though it looks like I am accessing everything the right way.

What should I do to isolate the cause of this issue?

**EDIT (partial solution) :**
In my case, I had a custom geometry and used the `SCNGeometrySource(vertices: [SCNVector3])` initialiser. As far as I can tell there seems be a bug causing incorrect allocations on what `source.data` returns. The way around this is not to use the `SCNGeometrySource(vertices: [SCNVector3])` initialiser anymore and to instead use the `SCNGeometrySource(data: ...)` initialiser. This fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

what do you call `Float3`? Is it the SIMD type [`float3`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/simd/float3)? In this case the stride would be 16, not 12 (SIMD types are aligned on 4 bytes).

```swift
print(MemoryLayout<float3>.stride) // 16
```

Comment: Thank you! I edited my question as there was indeed an error, but `withUnsafeBytes` automatically computes the stride so the error didn't come from there. From what I see it seems to be a framework bug.

Comment: Updated my question with partial solution.